# Angular RC2 and IE 9

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-9, browserstack

When testing my Angular 2 app in BrowserStack IE 9 (RC 2 currently) I noticed that my app throws the "Access is Denied" error. On my local was working fine and this is why: if  I change my Internet Options - Local Intranet to medium-low or low teh app loads just fine. If I change to Medium or higher , I get the error. 
I need to support IE 9. Any ideas appreciated . 
Here is my index file :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-feature.html">
<noscript>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=no-feature.html">
</noscript>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>POC</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="Angular 2 Starter">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="lib/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="lib/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="lib/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- DO NOT CHANGE THE ORDER OF THESE DEPENDENCIES!! -->
    <script src="lib/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="customizr.js"></script>
    <script>
        if(missingFeatures.count !== 0){
            window.location.href = 'no-feature.html'
        }
    </script>  
    <script src="lib/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/ng2-translate.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/hammer.js"></script>
<head>

<body>

    <main>
        <app-container>
            Loading...
        </app-container>
    </main>

</body>
<script>
    System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
<script>
if (window.location.search.indexOf('?customer=deutz') === 0)
    document.write('<link href="styles/deutz/customer.css" rel="stylesheet" />');
else if (window.location.search.indexOf('?customer=sunbelt') === 0)
    document.write('<link href="styles/sunbelt/customer.css" rel="stylesheet" />');
else
    document.write('<link href="styles/default/customer.css" rel="stylesheet" />');
</script>

<script src="ga.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: I thought IE9 is not supported by Angular 2

Comment: Nope, IE9 is not supported, and for good reasons

Comment: Yes, truth is Angular 2 does not support IE 9, but I have to somehow make it work as this are my business requirements. I used this shim : https://npmcdn.com/angular2@2.0.0-beta.17/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js and works fine when I load the app with the (in my case - localhost ) intranet settings "med-low" but get the error when set it to "medium"